# c# list.OrderBy not working at all?

Tags: c#

I have a hard time understanding how the `list.OrderBy` works and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong... I think it's something easy that I made some stupid mistake somewhere or that it's just working in another way than I understood. Anyways, what I want to do is sort a list from an attribute, I've made a simple program to illustrate what I mean.

```
class Hero
    {
        public int level;
        public Hero(int level)
        {
            this.level = level;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hero hero1 = new Hero(1);
            Hero hero3 = new Hero(3);
            Hero hero2 = new Hero(2);

            List<Hero> list = new List<Hero>();
            list.Add(hero1);
            list.Add(hero3);
            list.Add(hero2);
            list.OrderBy(x => x.level).ToList();
            foreach (Hero x in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.level);
            }
        }
    }
```

This gives the output:

```
1
3
2
```

While I would like the output:

```
1
2
3
```

Can anybody explain to me why it's not doing this and how I can fix it? I'm quite new with c#.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You *just* need to assign what `OrderBy` returns.

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.level).ToList();
```

Comment: Using *Sort* is better in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You should return result from `list.OrderBy(x => x.level)` to the same list:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.level).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

`OrderBy()` does not sort the `IEnumerable` that you input, but returns a new `IOrderedEnumerable`

This will work:

```
List<Hero> ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.level).ToList();
foreach (Hero x in ordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.level);
}
```

Or even

```
foreach (Hero x in list.OrderBy(x => x.level))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.level);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OrderBy()` returns ordered list and don't seve result to your list so you should assign result to your current list:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.level).ToList();
```

or if you don't want to save it you can do this in your `foreach`:

```
foreach (Hero x in list.OrderBy(x => x.level))
```

then `list` still contains default values before ordering.