How to sort an array of objects in to itself based on a property of said object?
I've got several classes generated from JSON code that I'm deserializing:
public class Rootobject
{
    public Section[] sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public string base_label { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Content[] contents { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    // main properties
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Label { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

I created a new object and a variable to access the Contents of a specific section:
public Rootobject editData = new Rootobject();
var itemData = editData.sections[x].contents;

The JSON gets deserialized into editData
I want to reorder the contents, sorting based on index number, the catch is, I don't want to create a new List, because editData is being used to serialize back into my original JSON file.
itemData.OrderByDescending(x => x.Index) did not appear to do anything, and itemData.contents.Sort((i1, i2) => i1.Index.CompareTo(i2.Index)); throws an error

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'array' because it is not a delegate type

So I'm unsure how to approach this.

"did not appear to do anything" - OrderByDescending returns an ordered enumerable.  Did you do anything with the returned result?  (e.g. assign it back to the object property where you want a sorted collection)

"did not appear to do anything" It returns a new IEnumerable

Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116653/c-sharp-list-orderby-not-working-at-all (strong dupe contender)

Yeah--so, I tried doing what was suggested in that post and did itemData = itemData.OrderBy(x => x.Index).ToList(); and get the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<JSONProject.Content>' to 'JSONProject.Content[]' ... I really did try to do my research on this one :( but I apologize for being green. What am I doing wrong here?

@Saturn what type is itemData? If it's not a List<JSONProject.Content> then you need to correct that.

@Saturn: It sounds like you want ToArray() instead of ToList(), as those are different types.  It's also worth noting that this will change what's in itemData, not what's in editData.  If you want to assign to a property in that object then you'd need to assign to that.  (e.g.: editData.sections[x].contents = editData.sections[x].contents.OrderBy(/*...*/).ToArray();)

@David that was the trick! Thank you!! I'm still a bit green so all of these different types were mixing me up. That solved it though :)


itemData.OrderByDescending(x => x.Index) did not appear to do anything

That depends on what you're expecting it to do.  What it does is return an ordered enumerable from the source data.  You need to assign that returned result to something.
For example:
editData.sections[x].contents = editData.sections[x].contents.OrderByDescending(x => x.Index).ToArray();

This would order the contents of editData.sections[x].contents and assign the result back to that same property.  (Note the addition of ToArray(), since OrderByDescending will return an instance of IOrderedEnumerable<Content> and your property is of type Content[].)

If you want to sort in place, the correct syntax is Array.Sort:
Array.Sort(itemData.contents, (i1, i2) => i1.Index.CompareTo(i2.Index));

